# Nginx regex to lower any uri expect files

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I am trying to write a regex that redirects any uppercase url to lowercase but it should exclude files.

```
location ~ ^[A-Z]?(?!.*(\.)).*$ {
    rewrite_by_lua_block {
      ngx.redirect(string.lower(ngx.var.uri), 301);
    }
  }
```

I tried different combinations but none working as expected, Please suggest any regex that should act on uri that contain Uppercase letter but ignores if it ends to be a file.

Examples:

```
https://wwwalls.com/category/Entertainment [match]
https://wwwalls.com/images/test.Png [dont match]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```bash
location ~ ^[^.]*[A-Z][^.]*$ {
   rewrite_by_lua_block {
      ngx.redirect(string.lower(ngx.var.uri), 301);
   }
}
```

Regex `^[^.]*[A-Z][^.]*$` will match any URI that has no DOT anywhere and must have at least one uppercase letter.